Collection is read-only Exception with EfCore Include method
I am encoutering error


System.NotSupportedException: Collection is read-only

when selecting Film aggregate from sql server with EfCore like this:
var film = await dbContext.Films
     .Include(f => f.CountryItems)
     .FirstOrDefaultAsync(f => f.Id == FilmId.Of(query.id), cancellationToken)

My Film Aggregate looks like this:
public class Film : Aggregate<FilmId>
    {
    private readonly List<CountryItem> _filmCountries = [];
    public IReadOnlyList<CountryItem> CountryItems => _filmCountries.AsReadOnly();
    ...
    }

CountryItem entity looks like this:
public class CountryItem : Entity<FilmCountryId>
{
    protected CountryItem() { }

    internal CountryItem(CountryName name, FilmId filmId)
    {
        Name = name;
        FilmId = filmId;
    }

    public CountryName Name { get; private set; } = default!;
    public FilmId FilmId { get; private set; } = default!;
}

Film Configuration for migration:
public class FilmsConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Film>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Film> builder)
    {
        builder.HasKey(f => f.Id);
        builder.Property(f => f.Id)
               .HasConversion(filmid => filmid.Value, f => FilmId.Of(f))
                .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
                .UseIdentityColumn();

        builder.HasMany(f => f.CountryItems)
                .WithOne()
                .HasForeignKey(c => c.FilmId);
    }
}

CountryItem configuration:
public class CountryItemsConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<CountryItem>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<CountryItem> builder)
    {
        builder.HasKey(c => c.Id);
        builder.Property(c => c.Id)
            .HasConversion(c => c.Value, id => FilmCountryId.Of(id))
            .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
            .UseIdentityColumn();

        builder.Property(c => c.Name).HasMaxLength(50).IsRequired()
            .HasConversion(c => c.Value, name => CountryName.Of(name));

        builder.Property(c => c.FilmId)
            .HasConversion(c => c.Value, c => FilmId.Of(c))
            .IsRequired();
    }
}

Can anyone tell what can go wrong in this case? Because it works in this case in other project:
 var orders = await dbContext.Orders
                .Include(o => o.OrderItems)
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(o=>o.Id == OrderId.Of(new Guid("7e761dbd-1aaa-4640-8db6-d12a883e4080")),cancellationToken);

public class Order : Aggregate<OrderId>
{
    private readonly List<OrderItem> _orderItems = new();
    public IReadOnlyCollection<OrderItem> OrderItems => _orderItems.AsReadOnly();
...
}
public class OrderItem : Entity<OrderItemId>
{
    protected OrderItem() { }

    internal OrderItem(OrderId orderId, ProductId productId, int quantity, decimal price)
    {
        Id = OrderItemId.Of(Guid.NewGuid());
        OrderId = orderId;
        ProductId = productId;
        Quantity = quantity;
        Price = price;
    }
    public OrderId OrderId { get; private set; } = default!;
    public ProductId ProductId { get; private set; } = default!;
    public int Quantity { get; private set; } = default!;
    public decimal Price { get; private set; } = default!;
}
public class OrderConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Order>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Order> builder)
    {
        builder.HasKey(o => o.Id);

        builder.Property(o => o.Id).HasConversion(
                        orderId => orderId.Value,
                        dbId => OrderId.Of(dbId));

        builder.HasMany(o => o.OrderItems)
            .WithOne()
            .HasForeignKey(oi => oi.OrderId);
    }
}
public class OrderItemConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<OrderItem>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<OrderItem> builder)
    {
        builder.HasKey(oi => oi.Id);

        builder.Property(oi => oi.Id).HasConversion(
                                   orderItemId => orderItemId.Value,
                                   dbId => OrderItemId.Of(dbId));

        builder.HasOne<Product>()
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(oi => oi.ProductId);

        builder.Property(oi => oi.Quantity).IsRequired();

        builder.Property(oi => oi.Price).IsRequired();
    }
}


Show other entities. Strange that they work.

@SvyatoslavDanyliv I have added Order example in my question which works in other project. I have found this example from Udemy course project. I have even tried to add this film example in that project and it was throwing the same error. Then I have tried a lot of things in that project and after some time it worked. Was thinking that changing name has to do something for migrations (have changed Country model to CountryItem), but it was not the case also.

Well probably EF Core found backing field  _orderItems by convention from OrderItems name. In your case it is not possible.  _filmCountries is too far in name from CountryItems. So, try to rename _filmCountries to _countryItems .

OMG. It worked, thank you so much. I have spent 24 hours on this :D

You can add this answer and I will mark it as answer @SvyatoslavDanyliv

Based on documentation how EF Core find backing fields. You should rename field _filmCountries to _countryItems.
It will enable automatic resolving how to store value for read-only properties.
